# PHP Trying to find a spefic line in text file and echo it

Tags: php, parsing

So I am trying to find a list of steam ID's in a scraped html file. This is what I have so far but it's not working, it is parsing an html page I saved as text and supposed to be outputting things with below variables and it is outputting a blank page.

```
   <?php
$filein = file('TF2U.txt');
foreach ($filein as $html) {
    $pattern = '#.*<a[^>]+href="steamcommunity.com/profiles/([0-9]+)/"#iA';
    $matches = NULL;
    $match_count = preg_match_all($pattern, $html, $matches);
    if ($match_count > 0) {
        echo implode($matches[1]);
        echo "<br>\n";
        }
}
?>
```

Any help would be awesome, I am not sure what I am missing but it's probably simple.

Comment: dont use regex to parse html http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags

Comment: if someone could post an example that would help, that link you posted had WAY too many random examples that none of which seem to do what I need, though maybe I am not sure what it is doing.

Comment: Replace `.*<a[^>]+href="steamcommunity.com/profiles/([0-9]+)/"` with `<a.*?href="steamcommunity.com/profiles/([0-9]+)/[^>]+"`, if it doesn't work, can you provide a "sample" of what's in TF2U.txt ? Because I think you could do it with a single preg_ function.

Comment: did not seem to work. I tried posting the file to pastebin but here it was too large so here is the original file. http://rghost.net/45431914. All I want essentially is a list of the numbers after the /profiles/ in a vertical line if it's simpler to do that

Comment: `$file = file_get_contents('TF2U.htm');
preg_match_all('#<a.*?href="(?:http://)steamcommunity.com/profiles/(?P<id>\d+)[^>]+#msi', $file, $matches);
print_r($matches['id']);` Enjoy, and don't do evil things with it :)

Comment: would you mind making that an answer so I can give you credit? =)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that the links aren't ending with a `/`, so here's a solution with some tweaks:

```
$file = file_get_contents('TF2U.htm');
preg_match_all('#<a.*?href="(?:http://)steamcommunity.com/profiles/(?P<id>\d+)[^‌​>]+#msi', $file, $matches);
print_r($matches['id']);
```

Comment: Worked like a charm, was able to use this to parse all 100,000 lines =) Thanks a ton!